# Dual boot with windows 8.1 "write the changes to disks?" problem

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have a pop-up message while installing Ubuntu alongside Windows:

[image: screenshot]

Is it normal? **If i continue is it format my entire hard disk?** What should i do?

Comment: Why you tried something else option?Is there any problem to install directly alongside 8.1?

Comment: There was no "install  alongside 8.1" option. @Ravan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is **perfectly Normal**. I have installed Ubuntu many times with this message being shown up. It just writes the new partition(s) on the Hard Drive which you want to create.
And No, **It will not format you entire Hard Disk**, but only the new partition(s) you have created.
So it is perfectly safe to click *continue* and proceed ahead.